# How to change 3dot main toolbar icon by code?

Tags: codenameone

How may I change the toolbar icon "3dots" with my own image by code?

I can add an additional icon to the main toolbar:

```
Toolbar tb = hi.getToolbar();

    Image icon = null;
    try {
        icon = Image.createImage("/3.png");
    } catch (IOException ex) {}
    tb.addCommandToLeftBar(EAST, icon, (e) -> Log.p("Clicked"));
```

This places the icon near the 3dot.
How may I change the 3dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing the three dots with the hamburger menu. The hamburger is on the left and the three dots is on the right when you add a command to the overflow menu.

You can hide the hamburger menu or replace it with an arbitrary icon only thru theme constants specifically `hideLeftSideMenuBool`, `menuImage` etc.

See: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html